# Drupal - Multi language site - Home page language is hardcoded

Tags: url, drupal, localization, internationalization

I'm to setup a Drupal (version 7) website with multilingual support. Being very new to Drupal, I can't seem to fix this simple issue: The default home page won't allow me to change the language (admin > configuration > system > informations), as you can see on this image:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/824/screenshot20111122at101.png

I could suppose this has to do with the configuration of a module, but can't find which one. I'd love the result to be for instant `http://localhost/?q=home` instead of including a language tag.

Answer (score 0):

1. enable the path module
2. set the same URL alias (eg: "home") for every node you want to be set as homepage, for every language.
   Eg: let's say that you have node/1 for english and node/2 for french as homepages. you should set the same alias for node/1 and node/2, something like "home" or "homepage" etc
3. go to admin > configuration > system > informations and set your homepage to that alias you set earlier.